# how to send mail using perl with attachement?

Tags: perl, email, smtp, sendmail

I've try to send mail using perl with attachment I've tried with `Email::Stuff` and  `MIME::Lite`,during run time i got some error as `Authentication failed` or server not connected can anybody help me?
corresponding code is:

```
   use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;
### Adjust sender, recipient and your SMTP mailhost
my $from_address = 'atme04@gmail.com';
my $to_address = 'thiyagu040@gmail.com';
my $mail_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

### Adjust subject and body message
my $subject = 'A message with 2 parts ...';
my $message_body = "Here's the attachment file(s) you wanted";
my $your_file_zip = 'my.zip';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $from_address,
  To => $to_address,
  Subject => $subject,
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', 'smtp.gmail.com' ,
                          Port =>465 ,
                          Timeout=>320 ,
                          Debug => 1 ,
                          Hello => $mail_host,
                          User  => $from_address,
                          Password  => 'Thiyagu.04' );
#$mime_msg->send() or die "Error sending message: $!\n";

#MIME::Lite->send('smtp',$mail_host,AuthUser=> $from_address, AuthPass=>"apssword");

$msg->send();
```

error message is;

```
 SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond aft
    er a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
     at mail.pl line 54.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: which package is sufficient to send mail with attachment?

Comment: it looks like the problem may be the configuration of your machine, rather than the module.  I recommend updating your question to include what system you are running on and what version of the relevant programs your system has.

Comment: ok dude let's consider this version of code!

Comment: in regards to the question of "which package is sufficient to send mail with attachment?", the module MIME::Lite is very good at it.

Comment: I would refrain from calling people "dude" or "yar".

Comment: @imran:ya it was nice module.i've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear to me. The problem is with your connection to the mail server - so changing the module that you're using is unlikely to achieve anything useful. I don't know enough about Gmail's server settings to comment on what the problem is, but [this page](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en) has some suggestions that you might follow. Specifically, you could check that the Gmail account has 'allow authentication' turned on and that your mail client (the Perl program) is using SSL for the connection.

Also, this might be easier if you used an email that was specifically designed for use with Gmail. [Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/release/Email-Send-SMTP-Gmail) looks tailor-made for your requirements.